# HttpResponseMessage not showing JSON content from MVC relay to Web Api

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api2

I am using an MVC relay controller to call a Web Api controller to get around the PUT limitation in forms/browsers. The relay works fine. The problem is that the response when displayed just shows the response code and headers and not the JSON content that is also returned.

Here is the code that does the relay:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UpdateTicket(int reference, TicketUpdateDTO ticket)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var baseUri = string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", Request.Url.Scheme,
        Request.Url.Host, Request.Url.Port == 80 ? string.Empty : ":" + Request.Url.Port);
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUri);
    HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.PutAsJsonAsync("api/Tickets/" + reference, ticket);
    var content = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return responseMessage;
}
```

And here is what is actually returned and displayed in a browser:

```
StatusCode: 201, ReasonPhrase: 'Created', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers: { Pragma: no-cache X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcRGV2ZWxvcFxFeHRyZW1lSVRTXEV4dHJlbWVJVFNcYXBpXFRpY2tldHNcMTAwMDAwMg==?= Cache-Control: no-cache Date: Fri, 26 Feb 2016 16:32:57 GMT Location: http://localhost:59413/api/tickets/1000002 Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0 X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Content-Length: 419 Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 Expires: -1 }
```

When I check the content, it is returning the object correctly in JSON format, but I am not sure why it isn't showing up in the browser with all the other parts of the HTTP response not shown.